# Scripting Add desktop users to Remote Desktop users group through PSEXEC

Tags: desktop, psexec

I am trying to create a script that I can run to add users to the remote desktop users group remotely through PSEXEC. I can run the following commands and it will succeed but I need it in script form so i can add multiple computers and users through an excel export:

psexec \remotecomputername cmd

netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable

netsh firewall set service remotedesktop enable

net localgroup “Remote Desktop Users” /add domain\name

reg add “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server” /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

This is what I have come up with as a script but every time i run it, it just sits at the PSEXEC screen right after it connects and doesn't run the other commands.

psexec \\computername -e cmd /c (netsh firewall set service remoteadmin enable ^& netsh firewall set service remotedesktop enable ^& net localgroup “Remote Desktop Users” /add Domain\username ^& reg add “HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server” /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f)

I have also tried ; and && in place of the ^& but it seems to fail after the remote in. This is just a point I am stuck at. Next I would like to have it tell me if it succeeded or failed. so if that could be added on the end as well would be where I go next.

Answer (score 1):

One method I've used in a restricted environment is a series of bat scripts. Create 3 bat scripts, and computer.txt file with the list of target computers. This has ugly logging but it works.

The 1st script loops through the list of computers, running the 2nd script on each computer in the target list.

```
REM Zip Script 1
@ECHO ON
CD /d D:\ScheduledTasks\Zip 
FOR /f %%1 IN (servers.txt) DO CALL PushZip.bat %%1
```

The 2nd script creates the file structure and copying out your PSEXEC and 3rd script to each of the target computer.

```
REM PushZip.bat Script 2
ECHO %2  >> DeployZip.log
ECHO %1  >> DeployZip.log
cd /d c:\ScheduledTasks\Zip
CMD /C MD "\\%1\D$\ScheduledTasks\Zip"
xcopy /Y c:\ScheduledTasks\Zip\PsExec.exe \\%1\c$\ScheduledTasks\Zip
xcopy /Y c:\ScheduledTasks\Zip\Zip.xml \\%1\c$\ScheduledTasks\Zip
xcopy /Y c:\ScheduledTasks\Zip\CreateZip_ScheduledTask.bat \\%1\c$\ScheduledTasks\Zip
timeout /t 1
PSEXEC -accepteula @servers.txt \\%1\c$\ScheduledTasks\Zip\CreateZip_ScheduledTask.bat >> DeployZip.log
```

The 3rd script runs the PSEXEC and script to each of the target computers.

```
REM CreateZip_ScheduledTask.bat 3rd Script
cd /d C:\ScheduledTasks\Zip
ECHO "CREATING TASK"
SCHTASKS /CREATE /TN CompanyTasks\Zip /XML "C:\ScheduledTasks\Zip\Zip.xml" >> CreateZip_ScheduledTask.log
ECHO "Does new Zip task exist?"
SCHTASKS /QUERY /TN CompanyTasks\Zip >> CreateZip_ScheduledTask.log
```

Comment: oh wow, that's intense. I was hoping it would be simple. OK, I am very familiar with cmd but when it comes to scripting I am at a loss. Let me see if i can add my netsh command in and get it to add the users to the groups. Thanks for the input.